# 2 problems with group actions on a finite set.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've got two problems, which I can't solve on my own so I ask you to help me a little, with some tips :)

1. Prove, that every action of group ( order 9 ) on a set of 8 elements has a fixed point.
2. Show the action of $S_3$ group on set of 5  elements without fixed points.

How should I start?

I know, that :

1. $G$ - group of order = 9, $X$ - set of 8 elements

$x$ is fixed point, if $G(x) = \{x\}$, so $g(x) = x$ for every single $g \in G$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the orbit-stablizer theorem, the orbit size divides the order of the group, i.e. $|O(x)|=(G:G_x)$ for $x\in X$. Hence the size of the orbits $O(x)$ can be $1,3,9$. Now $X$ has $8$ elements, so we obtain $k\cdot 1+\ell \cdot 3=8$, which implies $k\ge 1$. Hence we have an orbit of size $1$.

More generally we have:

**Theorem**: Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group acting on a finite set $X$. Let $X^G$ denote the subset of $X$ consisting of those elements fixed by $G$. Then $|X^G| \equiv |X| \bmod p$; in particular, if $p \nmid |X|$,  then $G$ has a fixed point.

Answer (score 1):

For 1, show that the size of each orbit is either 1 or 3. An orbit of size 1 is what you want to show exists. For 2, split the set of 5 elements into a set with 2 elements and a set with 3 elements.